# Wording on "highly active question" message is awkward

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, protected-questions, post-notice

Is this where bug reports are delivered? The grammatical structure of the sentence containing the highlight seems awkward.

> **Highly active question.** Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this
>   question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from
>   spam and non-answer activity.

I'd expect the message to say something like: Earn 10 reputation **if** you answer this question...

[image]

Comment: There are couple "English" sites on SE network to ask such question - I'm not sure if it is on-topic here... Indeed "in order to answer" is reasonable syntax to "if you want to answer this question you need to have 10 reputation points"

Comment: "*Earn 10 reputation if you answer this question*" does not make it more correct or less awkward because that seems to guarantee that posting an answer gets you a prize of 10 rep.

Comment: How much reputation do I need to earn if I don't want to answer the question?

Comment: These are valid points. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have completely misinterpreted the message. Your proposed re-wording would convey the wrong information.

The message is not telling you that answering the question will gain you reputation. It is telling you that you *cannot* answer the question because you do not have enough reputation yet. In other words, there is a minimum reputation requirement in place to *prevent* spam and/or low-quality answers to that question. You don't meet the minimum reputation requirement yet, so you'll need to go find *other* questions to answer until you have proven yourself to the system.

Putting aside the misunderstanding, there is nothing wrong with the grammar of the message in its current form. The phrase "in order to" is very common in English and does not have an ambiguous meaning.

I do agree, however, that the wording of the message is confusing and could stand to be improved. These used to be called "protected" questions, which was much more accurate and self-explanatory. Now, they're called "highly-active" questions, even when they are not highly active. Someone also tried to make the message "friendlier", which means it no longer successfully conveys the intended meaning: that you currently cannot answer the question because you do not meet the minimum reputation threshold.

Comment: Oh, I did completely misinterpret that message! Thank you for the correction and the additional background information